# Why ubuntu has vi , emacs ,nano with os default?

Tags: 12.04, emacs, text-editor, vi, nano

I am new to ubuntu ..So basically an OS has an app for a purpose..
But ubuntu has three basic text-editors..like nano, vi, emacs ...

So what is the reason for that? and what are the advantages and disadvantages between these editors?

Comment: Ubuntu (Linux) is all about choice and freedom.

Comment: you forgot to mention `ed`, the line editor.

Comment: i have not used it yet Mr@Benoit..Any way thank you..but tell me what is that if you know..

Comment: Finally after long reading i got it..

[From a good stackexchange ][1]


 


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/986/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-vim-and-emacs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the two big ones:

- `vi` is installed by default on almost all Linux (and other Unix) systems for many decades. This makes it something like the lowest common denominator, the editor every Linux/Unix user should at least know a little bit about in order to fix small problems (and install other editors if they want). As a result of its ubiquity it is used by many system administrators. Note that in most cases `vi` is actually `vim` (VI improved).
- `emacs` has been around for almost as long as `vi`. Compared to `vi` it eats more system resources (although that isn't much of an issue anymore nowadays). In my experience, `emacs` is used less by system administrators, but more in the scientific world.

I would advise to learn at least one of these two editors, even though their learning curve is steeper than `nano`'s. They've been around for ages and are extremely powerful. When considering which of the two editors to choose, please beware of [the editor war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war). See also [this `unix.stackexchange.com` post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/986/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-vim-and-emacs).

As for `nano`, it is a 'follow-up' from the `pico` editor, that was used by the `pine` command line e-mail program. `nano` is easier to use for users that are new to the command line (basically because it list the keyboard shortcuts at the bottom of the screen).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has `nano` and `vi` as command line editor editor and `gedit` as GUI based text editor. Each of these has their own advantage and disadvantage which is too broad to explain here.

In short few editor are easy to use but less productive where as some are little complex but greatly productive.  However selecting any editor or software is matter of personal interest.